# gcloud cli gke response does not contain full addons

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have a GKE cluster. When I try to query the cluster using the `gcloud` CLI I get:

```json
{
  "addonsConfig": {
    "gcePersistentDiskCsiDriverConfig": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "kubernetesDashboard": {
      "disabled": true
    },
    "networkPolicyConfig": {
      "disabled": true
    }
  },
```

which is unfortunately is a partial response which misses other addons like http load balancing and hpa. do you know the reason?

Comment: Can you provide more information like which command you have used? Try this command `gcloud --project=<project-id> container clusters --region=<your region> describe cluster name --format=json | jq`. This will give the output of all the addons that you have in your cluster.

Comment: Exactly that command

Comment: Are you facing this in all the clusters or only in one cluster? Did you encounter this before? Can you try restarting the service and updating the [add-ons](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#addonsconfig) by using the [command](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#enabling_the) and verify the output.